# Comparing two groups that have paired data

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, paired-data

I have a group A (about 100 people) that took a pretest and post test and were scored as the question correct or not correct. I also have separate group B (about 150 people) that did a post test and pretest and were scored as correct and not correct.

Group A went from 30% correct to 50% correct. Group B went from 20% correct to 17% correct. What statistical test can I do that shows that Group A was a better treatment than group B.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use a **paired test of proportions.**

Run the test separately for Group A and for Group B. The paired test takes into account that the data are from the same person (not independent). Since you are looking at correct versus incorrect, we'll use a proportion (versus a paired test of means).

Here is a [link to a chapter](http://www.webassign.net/idcollabstat2/Chapter10.pdf) discussing the topic.

If you look at [this page from MedCalc](https://www.medcalc.org/manual/mcnemartest2.php) you'll see a 2 x 2 table which in your case would be pre-test and post-test, and one table for group A and one table for group B.